# Magento 2 : set value in session from js file

Tags: magento2, session

I want to save string from js file in session because i want to use that value in controller. How to save value in session from js file.

I want to save one string which size is 200kb. so i want to save it in session.

Is there any other way to pass value from js to controller then please mention in answer.

I want to passed value without using ajax. so how to set value in session.

Comment: without ajax it is not possible. you can you cookie instead of session

Comment: is it possible to store 200kb data in cookie?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Comment: you should use ajax call to save it in session

Comment: @MineshPatel Read my question.... I mention in the question that i don't want to use ajax

Comment: NOT POSSIBLE. read it again  "NOT POSSIBLE"

Answer (score 0):

You can just set below code in your phtml file to use ajax, You have to change your customurl in below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'frontname/index/index'?>";
            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    customdata1: 'test1',
                    customdata2: 'test2',
                },
            complete: function(response) {             
                country = response.responseJSON.default_country;
                state = response.responseJSON.state;         
                console.log(state+' '+country);   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

inside your controller file execute() method,

```
<?php
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

        $response = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
        $country = 'india';
        $state = 'gujarat';
        $response->setContents(
            $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode(
                [
                    'default_country' => $country,
                    'state' => $state,
                ]
            )
        );
        return $response;
    }
```